# Python: How to create an if/while loop to keep creating variables/dictionaries

Tags: python, loops

To start off, I have a moderate understanding of python, not so great knowledge of all its syntax though.

Question: How to create an if or while loop that keeps creating variables (to each will be assigned a dictionary via a predefined function)? Or something else that might be a better idea. Basically:

```
if "keep_entering":
    #create a new dictionary based on what user inputs
else:
    #take all the dictionaries that have been made and put them into a list
    #I already have a function to do this though
```

So I have seen this question asked, but not in the scope I am asking. I have a list of dictionaries, and only so because I want certain keys in that dictionary to remain tied only to that specific dictionary.

Example would be that each dictionary is a student, within the student dictionary lie keys representing their last name, first name, a score for an exam, etc. (a mix of integers and strings basically), but obviously I want those to remain tied to that student's name and other info (like an address or phone number). I can't then just make a big dictionary with a bunch of names and grades and etc., it wouldn't keep all the information linked together as far as I know.

```
{first: 'john', last: 'doe', score: 87}
```

Something else to consider is that there is a specific key within the student dictionary which is availability. It is a list of times (as integers, so only at an hour sharp) they would be available for something which I would be reading through in a separate loop. Further illustrates that I need all of the info in each dictionary to remain linked together and can't just make one big dictionary, again as far as I know.

```
{first: 'john', last: 'doe', score: 87, availability: [2,3,7,8,9]}
```

So of course I figured if/while "something" is true (basically while somebody is still entering info about students, like their names and grades and etc info), I need it to create a new variable to which is assigned a dictionary containing all this info (via an already predefined function). Once "something" is false I would compile each of these variables into a list which I already know how to do.

So then here we are, would greatly appreciate any help.

Comment: Sorry, but your question is not very clear. Could you simplify it please ?

Comment: Sorry I understand that was all quite wordy haha, I just put it simply in the second paragraph ("Question: How to create...").

Comment: what do you mean by " a big dictionary won't keep the info linked together " ??

Comment: I am going to have a large number of students, let's say around 50. Each has their own name, grade, contact info, and availability unique only to each of them obviously. Would creating one big dictionary consisting of all the info of all 50 students keep the info linked to the specific student to which they belong? Like if I had one big dictionary with the key 'scores' which has 50 entries, how can I keep those linked to the student to which they belong?

Comment: Are you considering to save your data to disk ? with files ??? on the other hand, what if you use a list of dictionaries ????

Comment: Would want to save within program or to files I guess? Program doesn't end at data entry, goes on to process the information in various ways after it is all entered. I already planned on making a list of dictionaries, I just want to know how do I keep creating dictionaries while 'some_variable' = True?

Comment: you want to make 50 entries every time you start your program ? :) not many people would like to use it... it's best practice if your program could read a file of data.. process them one-by-one in a single dictionary variable.. append to file ... delete from file... I hope you understand what I mean...

Comment: I wouldn't know exactly how many entries there are, it's taking input from the user. I just chose 50 because I know there will be a lot of students, well over 50 actually. That outside file idea might be easier though haha...but I don't fully understand how it would work. I need it to process various things, and then perform actions, but I can only do that once every student is entered, not as each is student is entered.

Comment: I'll prepare a sample for you.. believe me, you want to use files... not dictionaries flooding right and left...

Comment: Oh I don't doubt it knowing that it will be a lot of entries haha. That would be great, thank you very much!

Comment: are you using linux>? windows??? or mac ? and which version of python ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I recommend using a class (https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html) instead of a dictionary for your student record.  A class will add much more structure to your code in the long run.  Think of dictionaries as a more "free-form lookup table" (or a hashtable, if you will... since that's what they are).

```
class Student(object):
    def __init__(self, first, last, score):
        self.first = first
        self.last = last
        self.score = score
        self.availability = []
    def add_availability(self, availability_time):
        # make sure it's an integer
        if ( not isinstance( availability_time, int ) ):
            return False
        # check bounds
        if ( availability_time < 1 || availability_time > 10 ):
            return False
        # it checks out, add it up
        self.availability.push(availability_time)
        return True
```

Then your main loop...

```
students = []
while more_students:
    # first = ..logic for first name..
    # last = ..logic for last name..
    # score = ..logic for score..
    stud = Student(first,last,score)
    availability_text = ..get input..
    while availability_text != 'quit' #change to whatever termination text/method you want
         if not stud.add_availability(availability_text):
              print 'There was an error!'
         availability_text = ..get input..
    students.push(stud)
```

Comment: Those exclamation marks aren't valid Python syntax - use `not`.

Answer (score 0):

I have started a code that can help you get moving..
Please check below.
If you have any question, don't hesitate to ask.
I didn't write a complete solution.. it's past midnight here..  :)
you will have to change your data file name/location in the main function...

Regards,

--code starts here--

```
import os

def clrscr_():
    os.system('clear') #Check for compatibility with your OS

def prnt_menu():
    a = 'z'
    while (a not in '01234'):
        clrscr_()
        print 'Main Menu:\n----------'
        print '1 - Print DataBase'
        print '2 - Append to DataBase'
        print '3 - Edit Item'
        print '4 - Delete Item'
        print '0 - Exit'
        print ''
        a = raw_input('Your Choice: ')
    return a

def ask_to_create_empty_database_file(fname):
    a = 'z'
    print ('Would you like me to create empty database file for you?')
    while (a not in 'yYnN'):
        a = raw_input('(y = yes / n = no)')
    if (a in 'yY'):
        file(fname, 'w').close()

def print_database(fname, ttl):
    if (os.path.isfile(fname)):
        clrscr_()
        print '  | ',
        for it in ttl:
            print it, ' | ',
        print '\n'
        f = file(fname, 'r')
        content = f.readlines()
        content = [x.strip('\n') for x in content]
        f.close()
        for ln in content:
            print ln        
        print '\n'
        raw_input('Press Enter key to continue!')
    else:
        print 'Error! Database file does not Exist.'
        ask_to_create_empty_database_file(fname)

def append_to_database(fname, ttl):
    rVal = []
    for it in ttl:
        a = raw_input(it + ': ')
        rVal.append(a)
    f = file(fname, 'a')
    f.write(str(rVal))
    f.write('\n')
    f.close()
    print '\n'
    raw_input('Press Enter key to continue!')

def main():
    file_path = '/path/to/database.dat'
    titles_ = ['ID', 'First', 'Last', 'Phone', 'Score', 'Availability']
    stop_ = False
    while (not stop_):
        menu_ = prnt_menu()
        if (menu_ == '1'):
            print_database(file_path, titles_)
        elif (menu_ == '2'):
            append_to_database(file_path, titles_)
        elif (menu_ == '3'):
            #I leave this menu for you :)
            pass
        elif (menu_ == '4'):
            #I leave this menu for you :)
            pass
        else:
            print 'Good Bye! Program exited Safely.\n'
            stop_ = True

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```